# Get a pointer to the current BOOST_FOREACH element

Tags: c++, boost, boost-foreach

Given the following simple code:

```
list<MyClass> m_listOfOBjects;
....
MyClass* ptrToMyClass;
BOOST_FOREACH(MyClass object, m_listOfObjects)
{
      ptrToMyClass = &object
}
```

My question, is does the ptrToMyClass now points to a temporal object or to the real object in the list. If it's the first case is there some way to get a pointer to the object in the list instead of the temporal variable created by the BOOST_FOREACH loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the declaration `MyClass object`, `object` will be a copy, not the object in the list. Try to use reference,

```
BOOST_FOREACH(MyClass& object, m_listOfObjects)
{
      ptrToMyClass = &object;
}
```

Comment: So if we declare it as a reference I will be iterating over the elements on the list directly instead of creating copies you mean?